# How to load view without reloading the layout in MVC 4?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working with ASP.NET MVC 4. I've a slightly heavier "navigation menu" and "header" which common for all pages.

I've created all the menu and header stuff in a layout, but in each navigation, browser reloading the menu. Is there any possible way to prevent reloading of layout page?

I'm using _ViewStart.cshtml to bind the views with the layout.

Comment: Can you provide code examples or explain how your code works? Can you explain what the problem is? Reusing a navigation menu or a header is quite common, so I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: You can use partial views.

Comment: You can use partial views and while clicking on tabs make and ajax call to get your partial view and then replace your contents.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply Rowan...

You are right, reusing navigation is common. My issue is that, for each navigation, the common part also get refreshed.

My menu is quite heavier more than 20 items there. Here i don't want to reload the menu for each navigation from one view to another. My requirement is that when I click on a menu, the intended view should be loaded without reloading the menu and header.

Now i'm trying to do it with partial view. I can't post the original code because of my client copyrights.
If still something unclear, i'll create a sample application...

Comment: Thanks Chamika and Jatin...

I thing i'm in right way...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming this will be your menu HTML rendered

```
   <ul class="menu">
      <li><a href="/about/index">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="/contact/index">Contact</a></li>
   </ul>
   <div id="page-content">
   </div>
```

Your view pages will be created as partial views in the below structure

```
About/index.cshtml
Contact/index.cshtml
```

**Note:** MVC partial views will not have `<html> or <head> or <body>`, it will just have the content, similar to user control in ASP.Net. You `cannot use @section in partial views`

Now all you need is load this partial content using ajax and place it in the main placeholder div for a page content using javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("ul.menu a").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault(); // prevent default link button redirect behaviour     
  var url=$(this).attr("href");
  $('#page-content').load(url);
 });
});
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: The url remains the same, however.

Answer (score 1):

You should try out caching the navigation menu and header if they are common to all the pages.

If your resultant view is made up of

1. header
2. navigation
3. menu content

and you could use a layout

```
@Html.RenderAction("header")
@Html.RenderAction("navigation")
@Render.Body()
```

where the "header" and "navigation" actions are cached heavily.

@Haacked mentioned this awesome blog post here http://haacked.com/archive/2009/05/11/donut-hole-caching.aspx

This approach cleanly separates out your concern for header and navigation. And you can focus on the actual content to be displayed by the Action currently called.

Hope this helps

Note :  This answer super simplified and you would have to take into consideration dynamic parameters and stuff while performing caching if your navigation based upon roles/permissions of users accessing the pages.

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to return a partial view from the controller:

```
return PartialView();
```

You could also override the _layout in the layout of the partial view being loaded by adding to the top:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
```